# VSTS: Test runner finds no tests

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a .net 4.6 MVC app and a standard test project which was generated by Visual Studio with a few controller tests. These all discover and pass in VS test runner but I'm trying to get VSTS to execute these tests now and fail the build if any tests fail. However, no tests are discovered and I get a lot of 'Input string not in the correct format' error.
I haven't changed anything in the tests and all I did was add the test task to my build phase.
Here is the full test output:

```
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2442325Z ##[section]Starting: Run Unit Tests
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z Version      : 2.2.3
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2017-11-28T09:54:11.2598856Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z ========================================================
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Test assemblies : **\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Test filter criteria : null
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Search folder : C:\agent\_work\1\s
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Run settings file : C:\agent\_work\1\s
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Run in parallel : false
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Run in isolation : false
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Path to custom adapters : null
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Other console options : null
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z Code coverage enabled : false
2017-11-28T09:54:14.6192312Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2017-11-28T09:54:16.7609946Z ========================================================
2017-11-28T09:54:19.1015214Z [command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @C:\agent\_work\_temp\18c48b81-d422-11e7-8218-574cad38a3a3.txt
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26228.0
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z vstest.console.exe 
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z /logger:"trx"
2017-11-28T09:54:26.1576050Z /TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent\_work\1\s"
2017-11-28T09:54:29.0388328Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-11-28T09:54:35.4463920Z Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.
2017-11-28T09:54:35.4463920Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:35.8082157Z Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2017-11-28T09:54:35.8082157Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:35.8394672Z Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.
2017-11-28T09:54:35.8394672Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:36.1206800Z Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.
2017-11-28T09:54:36.1206800Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:36.1676432Z Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.
2017-11-28T09:54:36.1676432Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:36.3706773Z Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.
2017-11-28T09:54:36.3706773Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:37.0547894Z Warning: No test is available in C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.17\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll C:\agent\_work\1\s\MVC5\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.17\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2017-11-28T09:54:37.0547894Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:37.0700167Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:37.6168898Z Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
2017-11-28T09:54:37.6168898Z 
2017-11-28T09:54:38.6066846Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2017-11-28T09:54:38.6066846Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Unit Tests
```

Has anyone come across this before? I kinda assumed that the standard Visual Studio test task in VSTS would run a standard test project generated by VS2017 by default!
Thanks

[image]

My SLN is a simple file->new app and has two projects:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The template provided in VSTS for the Visual Studio Test defaults the **Test Assemblies** parameter as:

```
**\*test*.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

Unfortunately, other assemblies may sneak into the search path.  Try adjusting the **Test Assemblies** to the following:

```
**\*test*.dll
!**\*TestAdapter*.dll       <--- changed
!**\*VisualStudio*.dll      <--- added
!**\obj\**
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **Test assemblies** in Visual Studio Test task to match the test project name.

For example, the name of your test project is **UnitTestProject1**, then change `**\*test*.dll` to `**\*UnitTest*.dll` in Test assemblies box.

Comment: I have tried that and get the exact same results. My test project has the word test in it so should get picked up either way.

Comment: What's the name of your test project? If the test assembly is in the configuration folder, you can use `**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll`. You can share the detail build log on the OneDrive (remove personal information).

Comment: Added the project structure to the original post. Also tried renaming it to MVC5AppTests in case it didn't like the full stop!

Comment: Here is the first build log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2oegclxoqssb5o/buildlog.txt?dl=0                      I have also added a brand new unit test project to see if it was project specific somehow. Exact same result.

Comment: Here is an additional build log with the second test project added: https://www.dropbox.com/s/84qx6isss4zw6rj/buildlog_22.txt?dl=0

Comment: @sheldon.cooper You specified `/p:OutDir` argument with `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (_work\1\a), so you need to specify `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` in Search folder of Visual Studio Test task.